# How to pause a .scrollTop() animation on mouseover? (jsfiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the following jquery code to create a slow scrolling animation.
http://jsfiddle.net/fhj45f21/

Unfortunately I am having difficulties pausing the animation on mouse over. Could someone please have a look and give me a hint?

```
function Scroller(y){

    this.times = 0;
    this.moveInter = 0;
    this.backInter = 0;

    this.moveBack = function () {

        var self = this;
        clearInterval(this.moveInter);
        this.backInter = setInterval(function () {
            self.times -= 5;
            y.scrollTop(self.times);
            if (self.times == 0) {
                return self.startMove();
            }
        }, 1);
    }

    this.move = function() {

        var self = this;
        this.moveInter = setInterval(function () {
            self.times++;
            y.scrollTop(self.times);
            if (self.times == 1200) {
                return self.moveBack();
            }
        }, 50);
    }

    this.startMove = function() {
        this.times = 0;
        var self = this;
        if (this.backInter != null) {
            clearInterval(this.backInter);
        }
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            self.move();
        }, 1000);
    }
}
jQuery('.textBox').each(function () {

    y = jQuery(this);
    var scroller = new Scroller(y);
    scroller.startMove();

});
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: y not stop the scroller on hover, and start again? http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/nxk4vseq/
add an y.hover handler with functions for mousein and mouseout

```
var scrl=this;
y.hover(function(){
    clearInterval(scrl.moveInter);
},function(){
    scrl.move();    
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is perfect! So simple :)